# javascript to get page number to add to href in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, anchor, hyperlink

I'm using kentico to make a website. Within kentico I am using a repeater to build different pages. I have my site set up to display 6 or so thumbnails and if you click on the thumbnail from the main page it takes you to the corresponding subpage. How I set it up was to have a global variable `i` and add 1 to `i` after each thumbnail loads. That works right so we can focus on the syntax for the link itself. I want to be able to have the url be something like 
`page.com/page/subpage?1` where the number 1 is the variable `i`. **I don't quite know how to incorporate this (javascript) into the href declaration. Is there a way to do that?**

I tried:
`<a href="/subpage?page= <script> type='text/javascript'>document.write(i);</script>">` I tried looking this up but I couldn't find any information to help. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a script tag into the middle of another tag. Instead, use the script to write the entire anchor tag. Watch out for unescaped quotations.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.write( "<a href='/subpage?page=" + i + "' > Link </a>" );
</script>
```

Comment: I assumed I couldn't put the script tag within the anchor tag but i didn't know how to do it correctly. let me try this way. it looks like it would work.

Comment: I had to move the `'` to the other side of the variable `i` but other than that this solved the problem. Thanks.